# Using JTable to print objects under different categories (ArrayList)

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I have a parent class called Item, that has a name, description. Then I have subclasses, such as Art, Jewelry, Automotive or Property. And I also have an ArrayList to store all my objects.

Let's say I have an Art Type

---

```
Name        Description      YearCreated   Artist
---------------------------------------------------
Monalisa    Famous piece     1503          Da Vinci
```

Then I have Jewerly Type

---

```
Name      Description         Gemstone    Designer        ExhibitionPlace
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Muse  Beautiful etc etc   Emerald     Tiffany & Co.   Victoria and Albert Museum
```

How can I use `JTable` to display my list, but avoid having unnecessary columns for each subtype?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends, what columns are you going to have?  Does `gemStone` belong in `yearCreated` column??

Comment: Name and Description are the only common variables between Art and Jewelry.

Comment: Unless you're willing to "merge" columns in some way, like `YearCreate/Gemstone/SomeOtherProperty`, I'm not sure you can.  Doing something like that would be rather confusing, as a user

Comment: I know. I have decided to create a drop down list, and the user will choose which type of item they want to display. Now, Is there a way of filtering ? In other words, is there a way to choose the specific type that you want to display, out of an arraylist of different types?

Comment: Yes, take look at the JTable tutorial from oracle, How to use Tables, it has a number of examples

Comment: Another idea would be to create a TableModel to hold each type of object and then, when the user changes the selection, switch models, this way, it's easier to manage the different column requirements....

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late reply.